# How do I compute the counts of one column based on the values of two others in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that includes three columns:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,2,3,3],
                   'B': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0],                
                   'C': [0.0, 3.5, 1.2, 2.1, 3.1, 0.0]})
```

Now, obviously I can use `df['A'].value_counts()` to get me the counts of the values in column `A`:

```
df['A'].value_counts()
3    3
2    2
1    1
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

However, what I *need* is to be able to change the value of the count based on the relationship between `B` and `C`.

For instance:

```
df['B'][0] - df['C'][0]
1.0
df['B'][1] - df['C'][1]
-1.5
```

Im my case, I would like sums `> 0` to count as 1, sums `< 0` to count as -1, and sums of `0` to count as, well, 0.

So for my purposes, having `B` and `C` turn into something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':      [1,  2, 3,  2,  3, 3],
                   'counts': [1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1]})
```

And then somehow be able to translate that into:

```
3  2
1  1
2 -2
```

Is what I'm after. How would I do this using pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['counts'] = np.sign(df.B - df.C)    # use the numpy.sign to create the count column
df.groupby('A')['counts'].sum()        # group the counts by column A and sum the value

#A
#1    1.0
#2   -2.0
#3    1.0
#Name: counts, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

```
df['counts'] = 0
df.loc[df['B'] - df['C'] > 0, 'counts'] = 1
df.loc[df['B'] - df['C'] < 0, 'counts'] = -1
```

Comment: One question: when I do `df[['A', 'counts']].groupby('A').aggregate(sum); df`, in the left column I have `A, 1, 2, 3` and `<blank>, 1, -2, 1`. Do you know why the `A/blank` part appears in the output?